# 3 LEFT-JOIN in Spark SQL with API JAVA

Tags: java, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I have 3 dataset in origin from 3 tables:

```
Dataset<TABLE1> bbdd_one = map.get("TABLE1").as(Encoders.bean(TABLE1.class)).alias("TABLE1");
Dataset<TABLE2> bbdd_two = map.get("TABLE2").as(Encoders.bean(TABLE2.class)).alias("TABLE2");
Dataset<TABLE3> bbdd_three = map.get("TABLE3").as(Encoders.bean(TABLE3.class)).alias("TABLE3");
```

and I want to do a triple left-join on it and write it in an output .parquet

The sql JOIN statement is similar to this:

```
SELECT one.field, ........, two.field ....., three.field, ... four.field
FROM TABLE1 one
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 two ON two.field = one.field
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 three ON three.field = one.field AND three.field = one.field
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 four ON four.field = one.field AND four.field = one.otherfield
WHERE one.field = 'whatever'
```

How can do this with JAVA API? Is it possible? I did an example with only one join but with 3 seems difficult.

PS: My other join with JAVA API is:

```
Dataset<TJOINED> ds_joined = ds_table1
                        .join(ds_table2,
                                JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList("fieldInCommon1", "fieldInCommon2", "fieldInCommon3", "fieldInCommon4"))
                                        .seq(),
                                "inner")
                        .select("a lot of fields", ... "more fields")                                                               
                        .as(Encoders.bean(TJOINED.class));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried chaining join statements?
I don't often code in Java so this is just a guess

```
Dataset<TJOINED> ds_joined = ds_table1
    .join(
        ds_table2,
        JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList(...)).seq(),
        "left"
    )
    .join(
        ds_table3,
        JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList(...)).seq(),
        "left"
    )
    .join(
        ds_table4,
        JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList(...)).seq(),
        "left"
    )
    .select(...)
    .as(Encoders.bean(TJOINED.class))
```

Update: If my understanding is correct, `ds_table3` and `ds_table4` are the same and they are joined on different field. Then maybe this updated answer, which is given in Scala since it's what I'm used to working with, might achieve what you want. Here's the full working example:

```
import spark.implicits._

case class TABLE1(f1: Int, f2: Int, f3: Int, f4: Int, f5:Int)
case class TABLE2(f1: Int, f2: Int, vTable2: Int)
case class TABLE3(f3: Int, f4: Int, vTable3: Int)

val one = spark.createDataset[TABLE1](Seq(TABLE1(1,2,3,4,5), TABLE1(1,3,4,5,6)))
//one.show()
//+---+---+---+---+---+
//| f1| f2| f3| f4| f5|
//+---+---+---+---+---+
//|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
//|  1|  3|  4|  5|  6|
//+---+---+---+---+---+

val two = spark.createDataset[TABLE2](Seq(TABLE2(1,2,20)))
//two.show()
//+---+---+-------+
//| f1| f2|vTable2|
//+---+---+-------+
//|  1|  2|     20|
//+---+---+-------+

val three = spark.createDataset[TABLE3](Seq(TABLE3(3,4,20), TABLE3(3,5,50)))
//three.show()
//+---+---+-------+
//| f3| f4|vTable3|
//+---+---+-------+
//|  3|  4|     20|
//|  3|  5|     50|
//+---+---+-------+

val result = one
.join(two, Seq("f1", "f2"), "left")
.join(three, Seq("f3", "f4"), "left")
.join(
  three.withColumnRenamed("f4", "f5").withColumnRenamed("vTable3", "vTable4"),
  Seq("f3", "f5"),
  "left"
)
//result.show()
//+---+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
//| f3| f5| f4| f1| f2|vTable2|vTable3|vTable4|
//+---+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
//|  3|  5|  4|  1|  2|     20|     20|     50|
//|  4|  6|  5|  1|  3|   null|   null|   null|
//+---+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: your approach is good but the problem is the 2nd and 3th JOIN (same table) and specifically this:

LEFT JOIN TABLE3 three ON three.field = one.field AND three.field = one.field (the name matches)

LEFT JOIN TABLE3 four ON four.field = one.field AND four.field = one.otherfield (the name of the master table does not match the name of TABLE3)

Comment: throws the following exception:
 UNNAMED with exception org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: USING column `one.otherfield` cannot be resolved on the right side of the join

Comment: I assume we'll have something like this:

TABLE1 (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5)

TABLE2 (f1, f2)

TABLE3 (f3,f4)

then at the 3rd join you want to do something like:
`LEFT JOIN TABLE3 four on four.f3 = one.f3 and four.f4 = one.f5`

I think it can be achieve by temporary saving the result of first 2 joins and perform the last. I am used to working with Dataset<Row> so I'm not really how things work with these types of Dataset

Comment: Your answers worked!, sorry for late but thanks a lot!!